# How to list database columns that contain a substring in their name and whether they are nullable or not

Tags: mysql, sql

I needed to check for nullable columns in a database column namespace (columns that have a certain token in their name). I'm answering this for my own future reference...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL only Show columns which allow null](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/mysql-only-show-columns-which-allow-null).

Answer (score 0):

This query lists all columns in the `<database>` with `token` in their name and their nullable status:

```
SELECT table_name,table_schema,column_name, `IS_NULLABLE` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE column_name LIKE '%token%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='<database>'
```